# Epic and Legendary Badge description says Legendary is easier to achieve than Epic. A Typo?

Tags: support, badges, daily-reputation-badges

I noticed in the https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges link the description of the Epic and Legendary badges are as follows:

```
(Gold) Legendary: Earned at least 200 reputation on 150 days. 
(Silver) Epic   : Earned at least 200 reputation on 50 days.
```

Same errors in pages too: https://stackoverflow.com/badges/145/epic and https://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary

what is going on, the description indicates who are Epic are also Legendary.

**UPDATE**

The language was ambiguous and therefor i guess now the description has changed in the badges page now it shows:

```
(Gold) Legendary:   Earned 200 daily reputation 150 times 
(Silver) Epic   :   Earned 200 daily reputation 50 times
```

Comment: what? 200 on 150 days is more difficult than 200 on 50 days. Not following.

Comment: god knows, why they voted down.

Comment: @phoxis: him too, yes

Comment: if you look now carefully then you will notice that they have changed the text. Now it says:  "Epic Earned 200 daily reputation 50 times" this is better...

Comment: @all: the badge description text was updated, and now it is much clear, as the ambiguity is removed.

Comment: See also [Change description of Epic and Legendary badges to avoid confusion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91726/155585).

Comment: _Response to "god knows, why they voted down"_: I downvoted this because "in" and "on" are not the same word. There was nothing wrong with the description, you simply misread it. (That said, the new text _is_ clearer.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It says "on X days", not "in X days".

That is, if you have 50 days where you earned at least 200 reputation on each, you get Epic.
For Legendary, the same goes, only for 150 days.

If it was earning 200 reputation over a period of 50/150 days, then you'd be correct.

My guess would be that the confusion stems from that misunderstanding?

Comment: You mean "there exists atleast 50 days for which atleast 200 reputations has been achieved on each of the those 50 days for Epic, and a similar argument for the Legendary for 150 days?

Comment: @phoxis: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was really confusing.

Comment: @Sebastian this isn't consecutive days is it?  Just total right?

Comment: @Tom: My guess would be total, but I am not sure.

Comment: @Tom @Sebastien: I confirm: "total of 50/150 days", not "50/150 consecutive days"

Comment: the badge description text was updated, and now it is much clear, as the ambiguity is removed.