# Change description of Epic and Legendary badges to avoid confusion

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

Can we make a small change to the Epic and Legendary badge descriptions to avoid the ongoing confusion about their meaning with some users?

Existing:

- Epic - Earned at least 200 reputation on 50 days

Proposal:

- Epic - Earned at least 200 reputation on 50 separate days

The reason I'm proposing it is because I suggested it here on meta:

- [Epic Badge: Earned at least 200 reputation on 50 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91591/epic-badge-earned-at-least-200-reputation-on-50-days/91593#comment-228353)

and two people said it was a great comment.

It's especially heart-wrenching because people see the badge ahead of time as one they can realistically earn and they peel days off the calendar until their dream can come true, only to be dashed by a misunderstanding.

Comment: It sounds like you're reading the existing interpretation to say "Earned at least 200 reputation **in** 50 days". That's not what it says, though. Adding "separate" seems redundant.

Comment: @Cody: **I'm** not reading it that way.  It's perfectly clear to me.  In other languages "in" and "on" can mean the same thing and it's confusing to them.  Or I don't know why people read **in** instead of **on** but they keep doing it.

Comment: **Epic - Hit the reputation cap 50 times** IMO is more clear.

Comment: @Nick: See my comment to Conrad's answer - this (essentially) was the old description, but it was _wrong_.

Comment: **Epic - Earned 200 daily reputation 50 times** - @Hendrik

Comment: @Nick: That should be an answer!!

Comment: @Hendrik: ok, done :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I myself find the current descriptions a bit confusing, so I came up with alternative descriptions:

> **Epic** - Earned 200 daily reputation 50 times
>
> **Legendary** - Earned 200 daily reputation 150 times

Comment: +1, I like this: It's concise and unambiguous.

Comment: "Our survey said!" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Feud

Comment: **Update:** This suggestion was implemented today.

Comment: @Rick, hooray! The update was made in revision `2011.6.3.1`

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think the older description was better.

> Hit the reputation cap on 50 days

Comment: This old description had the problem [that it was _wrong_,](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88465/mortarboard-badges-being-awarded-as-a-result-of-bounties-after-recalc/88526#88526) and there was endless confusion about it, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the description of the badges could benefit from a rewording as there is too much potential to misinterpret what it means.  It could be clearer.  Though the wording you suggest might not be as great.  I would suggest something along the lines of:

```
Epic:      Earned at least 200 reputation in a day for 50 days.
Legendary: Earned at least 200 reputation in a day for 150 days.
```

Comment: Sheesh, tough crowd.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure a change is urgent once a few questions on Meta such as yours have been posted, commented, etc.

Meta could be considered a running commentary of all the parts of Stack Exchange, like jurisprudence and previous decisions in court of law.

Long before reaching the quotas for Epic, 
200 reputations point during 10 days will make him reach 2000 points, earn several badges and many privileges and will give him/her a lot of practice and a different view of the system.

A potential Epic or Legendary user is certainly expected to use Meta to know more about the system and will find the explanations in this very question for instance.

There is also the great post [Badge explanations (including Area51) in two alphabetical lists and a few](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) .

Comment: I feel like I'm in a David Lynch movie.

Comment: @Rick : nice. Just relax and enjoy the show. The characters aren't real, they just pretend to be.

Answer (score 0):

I think the misunderstanding here is nothing to do with days or count of reputation...it is the word **earned**.

If a person has 200 rep and sits on that for 50 days, they haven't earned anything...they've done nothing...they are effectively subsituting the word "earned" with "maintained".

my proposal is no change...