# Wrong description in the Stack Overflow badges?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, daily-reputation-badges

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Change description of Epic and Legendary badges to avoid confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91726/change-description-of-epic-and-legendary-badges-to-avoid-confusion)
>   [Epic and Legendary Badge description says Legendary is easier to achieve than Epic. A Typo?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91441/epic-and-legendary-badge-description-says-legendary-is-easier-to-achieve-than-epi)

Here's three badges with their description:

- Mortarboard (bronze) : Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day
- Epic (silver) : Earned at least 200 reputation on 50 days
- Legendary (gold) : Earned at least 200 reputation on 150 days

Tell me if I'm wrong, but I believe earning at least 200 reputation in a single day **is more difficult than** earning the same reputation in 150 days.

But, the rewarded badge is more valuable in 150 days than in 1.

Is there something I don't understand, or is there an error, like for the gold, it would be earning 2000 instead of 200. Well, a "wrong label" for those badges?

Comment: So the request should be changing the text to something like "Earned at least 200 reputation per day, on 50 days"

Comment: A [similar person who ran into the same point of confusion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91441/epic-and-legendary-badge-description-says-legendary-is-easier-to-achieve-than-epi).

Comment: "On" vs. "in", once again. I think it's pretty clear for native speakers, but those are probably in the minority now.

Comment: Agree with you @mmyers, "on" vs "in" should be obvious for native speakers. I'm not a native one and I made the mistake. But it's also probably my lack of language.

Comment: But, I think the difference between the two words is so small (one letter) that result in a confusion for a lot of people : not native ones, and those who read quickly (and badly, I agree). That's why, despite my error in the understanding of the description, a renaming should be taken into consideration.

Comment: Finally, the changes were made apparently :)

Answer (score 15):

Personally, I think the descriptions should really spell it out loud and clear. This confusion seems to happen all the time.

- Mortarboard (bronze) : Earned 200 or more reputation in a single day
- Epic (silver) : Earned 200 or more reputation in a single day, 50 times
- Legendary (gold) : Earned 200 or more reputation in a single day, 150 times

Comment: on vs in  is so  difficult,It's usefully to me

Answer (score 8):

That's 200 rep per day for 150 days. Not 200 over 150 days.